# Glassfish webapp auto-deployment

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-3

I am using Eclipse with Glassfish plugin with a complex project consisting of several webapps and EJB projects.

Each time I change some smallest thing in JSP or CSS, the whole webapp is redeployed, which wastes a lot of development time on waiting.

In Tomcat, which I use in parallel (also as an Eclipse "Server" added through Eclipse GUI), things work like a snap - everything is deployed right away without delay.

So, is there a way to enable partial/changes-only deployment of web applications for Glassfish v3.1 and latest Eclipse?

How do you quickly deploy your projects using Glassfish v3/Eclipse combination?

Comment: Have you opened an issue on the glassfishplugins jira? http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISHPLUGINS.  You are more likely to get a bug fix/enhancement by using that interface, since SO isn't really built to support the back and forth conversion that it will take to replicate your problem and formulate a code change/response.

Comment: Is this still a problem, or is it solved? I'm currently facing the same problem and and wants to solve it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answers your question but an alternative approach is suggested.

I have not seen the Glassfish plugin but while I use MyEclipse that contains deployment customization options. We do it using exploded deployment

- Go to manage deployment
- select externally launched
- Hit Add - Select Project
- Select the "Exploded deployment" (development mode)

This should take care of your faster deployment.